# how to fix Unexpected token create react-app import locales yaml

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, unexpected-token

I am trying to run test but always got an error said that

```
 /Users/syafilm/Sites/Javascript/search-giphy-two/src/locales/en.yml:5
         search-giphy: "Search Giphy here"

     SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

       1 | import i18next from 'i18next'
       2 |
       3 | const localeEn = require('locales/en.yml')
         |                  ^
       4 | const localeId = require('locales/id.yml')
       5 |
       6 | switch (document.documentElement.lang) {
```

npm run test and always got the same error even i just setup properly like the documentation

```
module.exports = {   
  setupFiles: ["./jest.setup.js"],
  verbose: true,   
  testRegex: "\\.test\(\.js|\.jsx)$",
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^api(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/api$1",
    "^components(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/components$1",
    "^utils(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/utils$1",
    "^pages(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/pages$1",
    "^locales(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/locales$1",
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga|yml)$": "<rootDir>/src/test/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
    "^.+\\.(css|less|scss|yaml)$": "identity-obj-proxy",   
  },   
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"],
  transform: {
    ".*\\.(yml)$": "yml",  
  } 
}
```